# Angular2 not updating the rendered view after I modify its dom

Tags: angular

I've in the template

```
  <span class="timeago" attr.datetime="{{info.lastDate}}">{{info.lastDate}}</span>
```

Then the DOM is modified by `timeago().render(document.querySelectorAll('.timeago'), "en");`

Now if I want to update the datetime using the model (changing the info.lastDate property in the angular component class instance) no update is pushed to the view.

I think angular as a sort of 'smart' way to detect manipulated DOM and prevent override, but I need such override.

Comment: Can you add your code on `how` you update the object `info`?

Comment: I update the `info` via `...res =>{ this.info.lastDate=res.lastActiveDate; }...` it's  in a `subscribe()` to a service function that does a server call

Comment: can you confirm that the view updates after model changes when you don't modify the dom?

Answer (score 0):

I was wrong, I simply didn't destoryed the old timeago widget instance (with timeago.cancel) so it was stuck on the view

Now that i added the properly destory method the view seems to update correctly